# Toggle / Accordion functionality is not working inside modal

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-accordion

I have index.html page. In that I have one view detail hyper link and I implemented accordion functionality in that same page itself (HTML, JS code), it working fine.

but my question is ONCLICK of view detail link I fired one custom modal popup window. I want integrate that accordion functionality inside of the modal window.

I retrieve my accordion functionality into html in this way

```
var buildHTML = $('#dealerdemopopup').html();
$("#multiSubModal").append(buildHTML);
```

The accordion html code is completely coming into modal window but the  `accordion/toggle` functionality is not working inside the modal..

I would like to know, the way retrieve HTML is correct..

please some one help me to address this asap. Advance thanks

```
This is accordion/Toggle HTML code in index.html file
------------------------------------------------------
<!-- Dealer Demo HTML START-->
<div class="dealerdemopopup" id="dealerdemopopup" style="display:block;">
<div class="dealer_demo" id="dealer_demo">
    <div class="dealer_accordion">
        <div class="expand"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="packageTitle">&lt;Package 01&gt;</a></div>
            <div class="collapse">
                <div class="accCntnt">
                    <p class="packageContent">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div style="height:5px;"></div> 
        <div class="expand"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="packageTitle">&lt;Package 02&gt;</a></div>
            <div class="collapse">
                <div class="accCntnt">
                    <p class="packageContent">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>  
        <div style="height:5px;"></div>
        <div class="expand"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="packageTitle">&lt;Package 03&gt;</a></div>
            <div class="collapse">
                <div class="accCntnt">
                    <p class="packageContent">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>  

    </div>  
</div> 
</div>
<!-- Dealer Demo HTML END-->


This is accordion/Toggle JS code in index.html file
---------------------------------------------------

<script  type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dealer_demo div.dealer_accordion:eq(0)').find('div.expand:eq(0)').addClass('openAd').end()
    .find('div.collapse:gt(0)').hide().end()
    .find('div.expand').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('openAd').siblings().removeClass('openAd').end()
        .next('div.collapse').slideToggle().siblings('div.collapse:visible').slideUp();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

The following JS code in other js file to create custom modal popup window
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
function dealerdemoPopup()
        {

            $("#modalHolder .modalContent #modalSpinner").remove();
            $("#multiSubModal").show();
            $("#multiSubModal").openModal();
            $("#multiSubModal").width(450);
            $("#multiSubModal .subTableDiv").hide();
            Cvp.modal.elem.sizeModal();
            var popTitle = '<h3>Package &amp; Features</h3>';
            var buildHTML = $('#dealerdemopopup').html();
            var buildClosebtn = '<div class="buttons"><a class="button2" style="float:right;" id="btnMulClose" href="javascript:void(0)"><span>Close</span></a></div>';
            $("#multiSubModal").append(popTitle, buildHTML, buildClosebtn);
            $("#btnMulClose").bind("click",function(){
            Cvp.modal.elem.closeModal();
            $("#multiSubModal").hide(); 
        });
        }
```

Comment: Your need to add more code in your question